# TCP Connection over website IP

Tags: vb.net, windows, tcp

Is there a way to setup an TCPListener to use an website ip address instead of an computer ip address. For example, instead of using 127.0.0.1, use 74.125.233.95 (Google's Ip address. Just used here for example). Here is my code I tried :

```
Dim hostname As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim ip As IPAddress() = hostname.AddressList
        Dim port As Integer 
        Dim localAddr As IPAddress 
        Dim server As TcpListener 
        Try

            port = 8080
            server = New TcpListener(ip(0), port)

            server.Start()
            RichTextBox1.AppendText("Listening on : " & ip(0).ToString & vbNewLine)
        Catch ex As Exception
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(ip(0).ToString & " : " & ex.Message & vbNewLine)
        End Try
```

The above code outputs :

```
74.125.233.95 : The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Is there any way to do this using TCPListener or some other method?

EDIT :

See the thing is, I want to create an app which can be controlled from anywhere in the world over the internet. I want to keep it as simple as possible so the user doesn't have to define port forwarding when using an router and also so that the firewall doesn't block it. So the best approach for me is that the app will listen for commands over my websites domain name.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Receive Google's requests?

Comment: @usr : No. Just used google's IP address as an example. The real one used by the code belongs to my own website

Comment: Again, what do you want to accomplish doing that?`

Comment: @usr : "See the thing is, I want to create an app which can be controlled from anywhere in the world over the internet. I want to keep it as simple as possible so the user doesn't have to define port forwarding when using an router and also so that the firewall doesn't block it. So the best approach for me is that the app will listen for commands over my websites domain name."

Comment: The best practice is to edit the question to add additional information. In short: You can't bind to an arbitrary IP and recieve something because "the internet" doesn't know that you did this and is unable to send IP packets to you. Even if the OS allowed you to bind to any address you would not receive anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't responsible for defining the IP address, it only binds to IP addresses that are configured by the operating system on the computer's network interfaces.

When you open up a port and listen with TcpListener, you are binding to an existing ethernet interface with an IP address (or all of them if you use 0.0.0.0 / INADDR_ANY).

EDIT: OP clarified, he wants to receive requests from and/or remote control an application he distributes without requirement that the user configure anything special like port forwarding.

The best way to do that is to use "push". Make all of your apps phone home.

You can do this without initiating a TCP connection from a central server to your app, instead have the apps connect to a central server on a public address and the server can then control the application by pushing commands/requests. The point is, this works from behind proxies and NAT firewalls without port-forwarding on the user's network. Your server needs to run on a public IP address. It doesn't really matter which end initiates the connection, once the connection is up, it is bidirectional.

Comment: See the thing is, I want to create an app which can be controlled from anywhere in the world over the internet. I want to keep it as simple as possible so the user doesn't have to define port forwarding when using an router and also so that the firewall doesn't block it. So the best approach for me is that the app will listen for commands over my websites domain name.

Comment: Oh, of course. Well your question is misleading, it sounds as if you wanted to bind to another IP address of a pre-existing site. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Do you maybe have some examples I can use? Please?

Comment: Your code above should work on a central server. You then need to write a client application that connects to it. The issue seems to be that you don't have a public facing server to run the listener on. Or do you?

Comment: Nope. Since the service needs to be online 24/7, I cannot run it on a central server. I use this app called LiveZilla which actually install an server on your website and then all the clients use the domain you defined. But the whole server is stored on your website, but I have no idea where to even start

Comment: So where is your website? That qualifies as a central server.

Comment: My Website is on a reseller hosting package. The domain is : www.xtremeav.co.za

Comment: I see. So I assume the problem you have is that you can't run arbitrary code on the server. So can you run PHP, Perl, Java, servlets, CGI, some other active page technology? If so, you can have your client contact the web server on the HTTP port and use HTTP services or actions of some sort to control it.

Comment: I have access to PHP and CGI. However, I only have PHP knowledge and none of CGI whatsoever and very Limited Java knowledge. I read about creating an WebService in VB.net, but my hosting is on linux so that didn't work at all

Comment: I recommend considering either my 1st suggestion above, and accomplish the remote control over HTTP, or to get more control, move to a service like digital ocean that gives you full control over a Linux server to run anything. Although I have my own rack in a datacenter elsewhere, I also lease a small VM at digital ocean just to have more public sites/projects segregated from my more sensitive data.

Comment: You can write your app through PHP, and create a specific page like "remotecontroller.php" that handles requests from remote clients and distributes any commands as needed. Your commands can be stored in a database. Just treat it like a connected session, except it is a disconnected "store and forward" session, but the overall concept still applies.

Comment: I have thought about using WebRequest and WebResponse, but I am very concerned about the users security. Maybe in the end, I will use this and just try to add as much security as I can to it

Comment: So use a unique username/password per user. Even more, use public keys. The scope of this question is pretty large, but security isn't unachievable, all the capability exists to use a secure page / web service with VB.NET

Comment: Maybe I should consider moving to windows based hosting. I will also give your suggestion a try and see what happens.

Comment: While Windows based hosting will allow you to create a web service more easily to integrate with your VB.NET app, it won't solve the underlying problem you have. When I said VB.NE I meant client, not server. You can integrate VB.NET with a Linux backend just fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create an app which can be controlled from anywhere in the world over the internet. I want to keep it as simple as possible so the user doesn't have to define port forwarding when using an router and also so that the firewall doesn't block it. So the best approach for me is that the app will listen for commands over my websites domain name.

No, that's not the best approach at all. The best approach is for your application, and those who wish to control it, to connect to a central server that you provide and manage. The central server would relay the requests.

The approach that you are attempting makes no sense and will not work.

Comment: I actually want to use my website as the Central Server. That was what I was trying to do, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it. I've even spent countless hours on google, trying to figure something out

Comment: @Adriaan Why not ask a specific question about what problem you encountered getting your website to do it. Does your website work at all yet? If not, your question is about making a website that works, not about making an application.

Comment: My website is up and running. I just have no idea how to use it as an Central server. I was considering WebRequest and WebResponse (in VB.Net), however, I am very concerned about security. Something that works like TeamViewer could also work. Where the main application has an unique ID and you can the connect to it from the client app using that ID. Again, without having to configure port forwarding and firewall

Comment: I think what you need is a Web Service. Then anyone with proper authorization to use it, can.

Comment: @OneFineDay : The only problem with that is, my hosting is linux based. I have tried a Web Service but it didn't work at all

Comment: @Adriaan If your website is up and running, then users should be able to reach it and your application should be able to reach it. So it should be able to function as the central server. If you're having issues, ask about those issues. (Maybe your issue is "how can an app connect to a central web server?" I can't quite tell.)

Comment: How do you know the Service was up and running?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : Yes. That is one of the questions I have. I just want the user to be able to go to the website (example : http://myweb.com/TheRemoteApp) and be able to pass commands to the desktop app.

Comment: @OneFineDay : I tested it on Xampp on my laptop, but as soon as I changed the domain to that of my website, It didn't work. Like when in Xampp I went to 127.0.0.1/MyWebService it worked, but when on www.mywebsite.com/MyWebService, it gave an 404 error

Comment: That means it was not up and running. Maybe if it was configured right it would have.